# DOs and DON'Ts about asking PhD info to a Professor via email?

Tags: phd

I have serious doubts about how to ask PhD info to a professor, via email.
Is there a possibility that a professor don't want to answer me?
What I have to avoid to increase the possibility to obtain a response from them?
When I see a site announcing a PhD open positions and then the form to send an email, only to ask more info, I shortly describe myself, my skills, my MSc and then I ask info.
Maybe I am wrong?
Any suggestions?

Comment: You have a bunch of questions baked into a single, which as it turns out has been asked [here](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/20007/writing-emails-to-prospective-professors-about-phd?rq=1), and [here](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11658/questions-about-contacting-a-professor-for-getting-phd?rq=1)

Comment: This is not a real duplicate, but I think all parts of this question (and there are many) have been discussed here already.